# Qual o modo certo para passar variáveis para a pagina Create Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou fazendo meu ***TCC*** e tenho uma página de pré-cadastro, onde vão informações do tipo `[nome, email, senha, token]` e ela salva na table `pre_register`. Depois é enviado um `email` para a pessoa com um link, nele contem o seguinte:

> http://server/user/be848aa209755d11bd8657816d56cc34/kFoeu0JJMtMqe7yU233VyQfIR/create

Nele contém, após user, o `email` em `md5`, e depois da / tem o `token` e isso é enviado para o `controller` `UserController@createPreUser`, o método é esse:

```
public function createPreUser($mail, $token)
{
    $register = PreRegister::where('register_token', $token)->first();
    return redirect()->action('UserController@create', compact('register'));
}
```

Ele envia para outro método create:

```
public function create(Request $r)
{
     $user = PreRegister::find($r->register);
     return view('user.register', compact('user'));
}
```

Essa view tem o resto do cadastro, para preencher as informações desse jeito, eu só enviei para este metodo create pois ele deixa a URL assim:

> http://servidor/user/create?register=104

Se eu enviasse no outro método, ficaria uma URL gigante com email e token eu sei que estou fazendo as coisas erradas, pois está feio.

- O que posso melhorar?
- Tem como enviar estes dados para a `View` por `POST`, para que não fique aparecendo na URL?

Comment: Não entendi a ideia de précadastro. Se já tem os dados do usuário não precisa fazer mais nada... em todo caso envia só o token que redireciona para a página de create com dados já preenchidos. Nesse caso seu create seria mais um edit.

Comment: o pré-cadastro é porque a table de user é quase toda notnull, e não quero que o "primeiro" cadastro na home, seja cheio de campos... por isso faço um pre cadastro, com email e nome e senha, e depois da confirmação, preenche o resto dos campos...